# How can I change video source from webcam to file in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video, matlab-cvst

Could you please help me to change this code to work with file?
I make some change but got `Undefined function 'snapshot' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'.` error. Is there any alternative 
`snapshot` function for video file?

```
clear classes;

%% Instantiate video device, face detector, and KLT object tracker
%% vidObj = webcam;
vidObj = VideoReader('D:\Movie\a\tork\12 (71).mp4');
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector(); % Finds faces by default
tracker = MultiObjectTrackerKLT;

frame = snapshot(vidObj);
frameSize = size(frame);

videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[200 100 fliplr(frameSize(1:2)+30)]);

bboxes = [];
while isempty(bboxes)
    framergb = snapshot(vidObj);
    frame = rgb2gray(framergb);
    bboxes = faceDetector.step(frame);
end
tracker.addDetections(frame, bboxes);

frameNumber = 0;
keepRunning = true;
disp('Press Ctrl-C to exit...');
while keepRunning

    framergb = snapshot(vidObj);
    frame = rgb2gray(framergb);

    if mod(frameNumber, 10) == 0

        bboxes = 2 * faceDetector.step(imresize(frame, 0.5));
        if ~isempty(bboxes)
            tracker.addDetections(frame, bboxes);
        end
    else
        % Track faces
        tracker.track(frame);
    end

    displayFrame = insertObjectAnnotation(framergb, 'rectangle',...
        tracker.Bboxes, tracker.BoxIds);
    displayFrame = insertMarker(displayFrame, tracker.Points);
    videoPlayer.step(displayFrame);

    frameNumber = frameNumber + 1;
end

%% Clean up
release(videoPlayer);
```

Is it possible to easily do that?

Comment: If you read [the documentation for `videoreader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader-class.html) you will find [the `readFrame` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VideoReader` object does not have a `snapshot` method. It has a [readFrame](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html) method.

Alternatively, you can use the `vision.VideoFileReader` object and its `step()` method to read video frames. See [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html).

Comment: Hello sir!  There's someone that's asking a question about the CVST Toolbox in our MATLAB chat room that needs help.  Mind if you drop by? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in MATLAB reading of video stream from a camera vs from a file require the use of two separate functions: webcam or videoinput for camera and VideoReader or vision.VideoFileReader for reading from files.

To read from a file using VideoReader, use the readFrame method.